# DataBinding to a context menu in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls, command

I have a `UserControl`, defined like so:

```xml
<UserControl x:Name=userControlName>   
    <UserControl.Resources>      
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu >
                        <MenuItem Header="ITEM"
                                  Command="{Binding ElementName=userControlName, Path=DeleteCommand">                          
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controlType}">                        
                        <Grid>                            
                            <!--MyContentHere-->
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>        
        </Style>     
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
       <!--Content -->
       <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem> <!--is of Type MyControl-->
       </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This does not work, as the userControlName's `DataContext` is not being found.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try `PlacementTarget`. There are many samples at SO like http://stackoverflow.com/a/1022156/620360 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/5357124/620360.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a WPF [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx) binding like such:

```xml
 <ContextMenu >
    <MenuItem Header="ITEM"
          Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}">                          
    </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Where are you assigning `DataContext`? You may have a problem with how your `DataContext` is being assigned. Take a [look at the Output Window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) and share any databinding errors.